# Syntax error with Excel VBA Execute CREATE TABLE

Tags: excel, vba

So I am working in Excel VBA as a front end calculator for some statistics testing. After going through all the steps I want to be able to save the raw data involved with the calculations. But the file would become far to large with the amount of data that will end up being used so I want to export to an Access database. I have most everything working for the information I can create premade tables for but I am having syntax problems with the CREATE TABLE feature.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub EndAndExport_Click()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbPath As String
Dim Tblname As String

'Single path name, position of the file should never change
dbPath = "\\qs-nas1\Data1\QA\Bottling Level Check Database.accdb"

'Connect to new database
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Protection against no information
If Sheet5.Range("A6").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "There is no data, please enter sample data"
Exit Sub
End If

'Opening the connection
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

'Entering data into a pre-existing table
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open "Bottling_Information", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
rst.AddNew
rst.Fields("Lot") = Cells(1, 2).Value
rst.Fields("Manufacturing Date") = Cells(1, 4).Value
rst.Fields("Bottling Date") = Cells(1, 6).Value
rst.Fields("Bottle Fill Amount") = Cells(3, 2).Value
rst.Update
rst.Close

'Setting variable as new table names value
Tblname = Sheet5.Cells(1, 2).Value

'Attempting to create the new table with the afformentioned string
'Where I get my syntax error
With cnn
 .Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Tblname & " ([MeasuredVolume] text(25), " & _
        "[MeasuredWeight] text(25), " & _
        "[CalculatedVolume] text(25))"
End With

'Rest of the code which should populate the newly created table
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open " & Tblname & ", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

For i = 1 To SampleLabel5
    rst.AddNew
    For j = 1 To 3
    rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i + 5, j + 1).Value
    Next j
    rst.Update
Next i

'Clearing the memory for my connection and recordset variables
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'Clears data that was exported
Sheet5.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(SampleLabel5 + 5, 4)).ClearContents
Sheet5.Cells(1, 2).ClearContents
Sheet5.Cells(1, 4).ClearContents
Sheet5.Cells(1, 6).ClearContents
Sheet5.Cells(3, 2).ClearContents
Sheet5.Cells(3, 5).ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H3:J3").ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H6:J6").ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H8:J10").ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H14:J14").ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H17:J17").ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("H19:J21").ClearContents
Sheet1.Activate

End Sub
```

The error I am getting is:

Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: What value do you have in cell B1 of the sheet with the `CodeName` of `Sheet5`?  (Does it have spaces in it, or some other character that requires you to put brackets, i.e. `[...]` around the table name?)

Comment: Currently its CSF1802/1 it will always have a character and 4 digit number and dash then number. No spaces but does the backslash require that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE CSF1802/1 (
       [MeasuredVolume] text(25), 
       [MeasuredWeight] text(25), 
       [CalculatedVolume] text(25)
                       )
```

is not valid due to the forward slash (`/`) in the table name.  You need a statement of

```
CREATE TABLE [CSF1802/1] (
       [MeasuredVolume] text(25), 
       [MeasuredWeight] text(25), 
       [CalculatedVolume] text(25)
                       )
```

To create that statement you need the VBA code

```
.Execute "CREATE TABLE [" & Tblname & "] ([MeasuredVolume] text(25), " & _
    "[MeasuredWeight] text(25), " & _
    "[CalculatedVolume] text(25))"
```